# ¿Cómo guardar los datos de una consulta en una tabla en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

Tengo una duda: ¿es posible guardar los datos de una consulta en una tabla nueva en MySQL?

Contexto: tengo dos tablas en MySQL. Una llamada `regis` con los siguientes campos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

... y la otra llamada `trabajos` con los siguientes campos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Generé esta consulta:

```php
//Consultamos la tabla regis
$consulta = $db->consulta("SELECT R.Nombre, R.Direccion, R.Telefono, R.Id_trabajo, R.Cantidad, R.Fecha_ingreso, R.Anticipo, T.nombre, T.costo , R.Cantidad*T.Costo AS Total, R.Cantidad*T.Costo-R.Anticipo AS Resta   FROM regis AS R JOIN trabajos AS T ON R.id_trabajo = T.id WHERE R.Nombre LIKE '%$buscar%'");
```

... y como resultado, me arroja la información siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, lo que quiero hacer es guardar esa consulta en una tabla para posteriormente editar los datos. Tengo dos botones: uno `EDITAR` y otro `ELIMINAR`. Por ejemplo, si el cliente me da un nuevo `Anticipo`, me voy a su registro y pongo un nuevo anticipo y que se guarde y actualice en mi tabla. Pero, ¿se puede? ¿Cómo lo hago? O, ¿qué me recomiendan?

Answer (score 5):

Partiendo de tu consulta:

```sql
SELECT R.Nombre, 
       R.Direccion, 
       R.Telefono, 
       R.Id_trabajo, 
       R.Cantidad, 
       R.Fecha_ingreso,
       R.Anticipo, 
       T.nombre, 
       T.costo, 
       R.Cantidad * T.Costo AS Total,
       R.Cantidad * T.Costo - R.Anticipo AS Resta
  FROM regis AS R
  JOIN trabajos AS T
    ON R.id_trabajo = T.id
 WHERE R.Nombre LIKE '%abc%'
```

Si tu deseo es guardar los resultados de esta consulta en una nueva tabla, la manera más sencilla de hacer esto es usando la sentencia [`create table ... as select ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html).

Por ejemplo, digamos que quieres guardar el resultado de tu consulta en una tabla llamada `resultados`, el SQL sería:

```sql
CREATE TABLE resultados AS -- agregas esto en frente y ¡ya!
SELECT R.Nombre, 
       R.Direccion, 
       R.Telefono, 
       R.Id_trabajo, 
       R.Cantidad, 
       R.Fecha_ingreso,
       R.Anticipo, 
       T.nombre, 
       T.costo, 
       R.Cantidad * T.Costo AS Total,
       R.Cantidad * T.Costo - R.Anticipo AS Resta
  FROM regis AS R
  JOIN trabajos AS T
    ON R.id_trabajo = T.id
 WHERE R.Nombre LIKE '%abc%'
```

Para más información sobre la sintaxis, el uso de `create table ... as select ...`, y opciones adicionales en su uso, aquí tienes la documentación al respecto: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html.

Comment: Es correcto lo que dice @sstan, pero asegurate, para la segunda vez que ejecutes el script/php, que la tabla no exista, o mejor aun, de borrarla porque el create te dará error, a partir de la segunda ejecucion, porque la tabla ya va a existir. Entonces "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `resultado`" y luego si la sentencia

Comment: @Emiliano: Gracias por mencionar ese punto muy pertinente.

Answer (score -2):

No sé si se pueda pero puedes usar una vista para guardar tu consulta. Al crear una vista también se genera una tabla que guarda los datos de la consulta que hayas hecho.

Comment: Una vista no genera una tabla que guarda los datos. Una vista es simplemente una forma conveniente de darle un nombre a una consulta.

Comment: y como se hace la vista?